# Is it possible to add persistent listeners with multiple arguments to a unity event?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been looking online for an answer for a while now, and can't find anything conclusive, which leads me to think you can't, but I thought it better to ask just to clarify.

I'm using a custom inspector window to handle text display, and I've got it to handle single argument functions with `AddIntPersistentListener`, `AddStringPersistentListener`, ect, but I want to be able to do more complicated things that require 2 or 3 parameters. Originally, I tried using a lambda for this, but it throws an error when I try to update the event.

I understand you can use a `UnityEvent<T0,T1,T2>` to have multiple arguments, but to my knowledge, those aren't persistent. I have a function that generates the event, so I could generate the event and then invoke it, meaning that it wouldn't have to be persistent, but I feel that would be clunky.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding persistent listeners is done with [UnityEventTools](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEventTools.AddPersistentListener.html).

But since you have used it for an UnityEvent with one parameter I think you know this.

Using lambda functions with not work for this as unity needs a reference so serialize in the listener.

```
using UnityEditor.Events; // works only in editor
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;


public class PersistentListenerExample: MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityEvent<int, string, float> OnMyEvent;

    private void Start()
    {
        int a = 1;
        string b = "2";
        float c = 3.0f;
        UnityEventTools.AddPersistentListener(OnMyEvent, OnMyEventFired);

    }

    public void OnMyEventFired(int a, string b, float c)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnMyEventFired with params: " + a + ", " + b + ", " + c);
    }
}
```